# is there some good ebook/tutorial about advanced google drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried searching for it but did not find anything at all. You got into something? I would like something advanced, such as something about folders, scriptability, sdk, and so on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All the documentation is on http://developers.google.com/drive. It contains information about all those things you mentioned. If you have any specific questions, please ask them?

There are no books as far as I know.

Comment: Well, a book would just ne much better. I mean something I can read on my sparetime to get a widespread knowledge about it, once every day. Of course I am already using stackoverflow for single issues, and found great help. Thank you.